The fecha field must match the format Y/m/d H:i:s
Estoy trabajando en un backend de laravel. Quiero inyectar un dato tipo datetime a traves de una input en una vista create. Aca el codigo:
    <div class="form-group mb-2 mb20 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        <label for="fecha" class="form-label">{{ __('Fecha') }}</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" name="fecha" class="form-control @error('fecha') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('fecha', $specialevent?->fecha) }}" id="fecha" placeholder="Fecha" step="1">
        {!! $errors->first('fecha', '<div class="invalid-feedback" role="alert"><strong>:message</strong></div>') !!}
    </div>

Mi regla de validacion es esta:
            'fecha' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s"',

El formato de la fecha que me reconoce el input es el siguiente:
31/10/2024 12:00:00

Usando la funcion de depuracion, me doy cuenta que el json que me devuelve el sistema correspondiente a ese campo es este:
 "fecha" => "2024-10-31T12:00:01"

He hecho varios cambios en la regla de validacion pero no dejo de recibir siempre la misma respuesta:
The fecha field must match the format Y/m/d H:i:s.


Estás usando datetime-local, el cual devuelve una fecha en el formato Y-m-d\TH:i:s, mientras que tu regla de validación espera Y-m-d H:i:s.
Como ves, ambas reglas están chocando, y por eso hay 2 opciones, o editamos la fecha obtenida, o cambiamos la regla.
Para editar la fecha que viene desde e JSON, podemos hacer un simple str_replace y quitar la T de en medio por un espacio.
Y para corregir la regla, solamente basta aceptar el formato correcto del JSON.
'fecha' => 'required|date_format:"Y-m-d\TH:i:s"'

Tienes algún controlador para esta data ? o como lo haces ?
Recomiendo siempre tener una validación manual mientras desarrollas, y que el error imprima el valor obtenido, para que sepas que es el error, y cual es el valor que te da el error.
